# How to replace/extend Django shell with Rich?

Tags: python, django, django-shell, rich

Django allows to [replace its default shell with more capable ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#shell) like `ipython` and `bpython`.

Is there a way to replace/extend the default Django shell with [Rich](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich)?

Comment: as far as I know, the `Rich` is not a ***Python interactive interpreter***

Answer (score 3):

Rich support an [IPython Extension](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#ipython-extension) which should work with the Django shell.

Comment: It's 1.5 years since this answer and you're extremely active. Is there an update?

Comment: been 2 years, thank you for taking this up. if there are any updates, they'll be great

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to do this without modifying Django itself.

The list of supported shells [is hard-coded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e74b3d724e5ddfef96d1d66bd1c58e7aae26fc85/django/core/management/commands/shell.py#L18) and [`ipython` and `bpython` have slightly different start-up logic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e74b3d724e5ddfef96d1d66bd1c58e7aae26fc85/django/core/management/commands/shell.py#L34-L40).